# ASP.NET MVC - logoff issue with IE when using common machineKey for cross-app auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I've an MVC5 project wherein modules are spread out across multiple web applications, deployed on a single IIS Server, single app pool.

Server: Windows 2008 R2 (SP1)
IIS: 7.5.7600.16385

Forms authentication is used and cross-application authentication is enabled by using common 'machineKey'

**Problem**
When using Internet Explorer 10/11 and do the steps below, cross-app authentication sharing no longer works.
1. Login and open another module
2. Signout
3. Login and open another module - !!gets redirected back to login page

This issue doesn't happen with Chrome and Firefox.

**Config Sample**

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

<machineKey validationKey="KEYXXX" 
            decryptionKey="KEYXXX" 
            validation="SHA1" 
            decryption="AES" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="/login/login.aspx" timeout="120" cookieless="AutoDetect" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
</authentication>
</system.web>
```

**Signout Code**

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
HttpContext.Session.Remove(MvcConstants.userContextSessionKey);
```

Appreciate help on this.

Comment: Just a thought: have you tried setting `cookieless` to false instead of auto-detect? I've seen ASP.Net's browser capability detection cause problems, i.e. it incorrectly thinks it is working with a very old browser and behaves differently. Apart from that, I suggest watching the traffic in your browser tools to see when the cookie is added/removed. If all else fails, remember that ASP.Net is open source.